# Shift result interpretation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp, shift

I want to add a new column `Datadiff`, which calculates the difference in adjacent `Data` rows for dataframe `df`:

```
        Id  Timestamp               Data       Timediff Datadiff
696     697 2013-08-12 10:35:47.287 30.0        0.510   -1.0
885     886 2013-08-12 10:37:35.850 30.5        -0.203  5.0
886     887 2013-08-12 10:37:36.373 31.5        0.523   1.0
917     918 2013-08-12 10:37:45.137 31.5        -0.510  34.5
1018   1019 2013-08-12 11:17:13.570 25.0        0.000   0.0
1357   1358 2013-08-12 12:42:21.280 25.0        -0.347  28.0
```

using code:

```
df['Timediff']= (df['Timestamp']-df['Timestamp'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds()
df['Datadiff']= (df['Data']-df['Data'].shift(1))
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df[df['Data']>0]
df.head(500)
```

But column `Datadiff` looks weird. How does shift(1) work? What is wrong?

Comment: I run code to your data sample and get different output, so weird means wrong data?

Comment: It seems that I didn't get the results I wanted because I have sliced the data which disrupted the index. So I guess I have to reset the index before applying shift.. Sorry my mistake missing out the information. But thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I think reset index is not necessary here

Comment: @jezrael Right I realised that I should have specified `df = df[df['Data']>0]` at the beginning, which will change the order the of dataframe that `shift()` applies on. Is that the reason why?

Comment: I understand now. I think problem is first shift and then remove data by condition. So because some rows are removed, then was shifting corect to original data, shifting by consecutive values of original. So in new filtered DataFrame new columns was not shifted by new filtered data, but by original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working correctly, compared by difference return same output:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df[df['Data']>0]

df['Timediff1']= (df['Timestamp']-df['Timestamp'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds()
df['Timediff2']= df['Timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds()

df['Datadiff1']= (df['Data']-df['Data'].shift(1))
df['Datadiff2']= df['Data'].diff()

print (df)
        Id               Timestamp  Data  Timediff  Datadiff  Timediff1  \
696    697 2013-08-12 10:35:47.287  30.0     0.510      -1.0        NaN   
885    886 2013-08-12 10:37:35.850  30.5    -0.203       5.0    108.563   
886    887 2013-08-12 10:37:36.373  31.5     0.523       1.0      0.523   
917    918 2013-08-12 10:37:45.137  31.5    -0.510      34.5      8.764   
1018  1019 2013-08-12 11:17:13.570  25.0     0.000       0.0   2368.433   
1357  1358 2013-08-12 12:42:21.280  25.0    -0.347      28.0   5107.710   

      Timediff2  Datadiff1  Datadiff2  
696         NaN        NaN        NaN  
885     108.563        0.5        0.5  
886       0.523        1.0        1.0  
917       8.764        0.0        0.0  
1018   2368.433       -6.5       -6.5  
1357   5107.710        0.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the index and then apply diff() operator:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df.reset_index()
df['Timediff']= df['Timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
df['Datadiff']= df['Data'].diff()
```

Comment: I figured that I should have sliced the data before applying shift. I guess that's why. But thank you for your help:)